# Angular-CLI - Import local packages from lib

Tags: npm, package, angular-cli

I am having trouble finding out how to import a package into an Angular-CLI app from the lib folder.  I tried adding the reference to the .umd.js and (separately) the index.js file in angular-cli.json, but when I try to import the module, it tells me it's not a NgModule.

Is there some configuration to tell it to import packages from the lib folder instead of just the node_modules folder?

Comment: This may help you: [ng cli global scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts)